# Rails form submit to new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a form taking a collection of names, a date, and another boolean via virtual attributes how can I submit them to a new page and action. That has nothing to do with CRUD. It will simply do some processing then spit out the values on a new page.

**personsSelection.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'myForm' %>
```

**_myForm.html**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@person) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :names, :collection => People.all, as => :check_boxes %>
<%= f.input :DateTime %>
<%= f.check_box :paid %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

**person_controller.erb**

```
def personReport
  #Some Random Processing
end
```

**personReport.html.erb**

```
#Display the personReport processing data
```

Again, I'm trying to submit the form to process via personReport action then display to a new page called personReport.html.erb

Comment: What is the exact problem you are running into? Trouble submitting the values to the correct action?

Comment: Yes, how can I direct it to that page using that action. Instead of the default trying to create a new @person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes

```
  match "/person/personreport" => "person#personReport", :as => personreport
```

In your form

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@person, :url => personreport_path) do |f| %>
```

This will send the data to your personReport action where you can process the data then by default that action will render personReport.html.erb